# CakePHP 2.8.4: Change User balance

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I wanna change the balance of an account in my table *Users*. But I want to do this in a another Controller instead of the UsersController.

M Code:

```html
 public function myfunctionname() {
    $this->layout = 'customer';
    $this->loadModel('User');

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
      // Some working stuff
    $this->User->updateAll(array('balance' => 'balance - 5'), array('customerid' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')));
        $this->MyControllerName->create();
        if ($this->MyControllerName->save($this->request->data)) {
          $this->Flash->success( __('Success!'));
          $this->redirect('some redirect');
        } else {
          $this->Flash->error( __('Error!'));
        }
    }
 }
```

I will get the following error:

```html
Database Error

Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'customerid' in 'where clause'

SQL Query: UPDATE `mydbname`.`users` AS `User` SET `User`.`balance` = balance - 5 WHERE `customerid` = '5'
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I got it:

```
$this->User->updateAll(array('balance' => 'balance - 5'), array('id' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')));
```